# What is overlapping in memmove() definition?

Tags: c++, c, overlapping

I was reading from a c++ reference about `memcpy`and `memmove` and they seems to be doing the same thing except that `memmove` has a specific think called (allowing the destination and source to overlap).

What is overlapping and when that happens?

Comment: overlapping is the usual definition....it means contiguous memory overlap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very simple.  Consider `memmove(dest, source, length)`.

If the range of bytes specified by the range `source` to `source + length - 1` include any bytes in the range specified by `dest` to `dest + length - 1`, the two ranges overlap.

This is most likely to happen when moving elements within an array.  Example:

```
// Slide array down by one:
char array[N];
memmove( (void*) &array[0], (void*) &array[1], N - 1 );
```

That overlaps on elements 1 through N-2.  Sliding the other direction has a similar overlap:

```
// Slide array up by one:
memmove( (void*) &array[1], (void*) &array[0], N - 1 );
```

If you were to attempt this same operation with `memcpy()`, the resulting behavior is undefined.  *Some* implementations will work correctly if you use `memcpy` in both examples above.  Others will fail for one or both of the two if you use `memcpy` here instead of `memmove`.  This is a consequence of the fact C and C++ leave the behavior undefined for `memcpy()` when the ranges overlap like this.

Comment: Or (POSIX): "The memcpy() function shall copy n bytes from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."  memmove allows the objects to overlap - and to gives expected results.

Comment: @Joe Z In your exemple will be the source lost or it will be copyed to other space in memory?

Comment: @rullof: Undefined behavior means "anything could happen," including reformatting your hard drive.  Most likely, though, the destination gets a garbled result, such as repeating strings of bytes.  And because destination and source overlap, that naturally means the source also gets corrupted.  I don't think I've witnessed `memcpy()` writing to bytes outside the range `dest` to `dest + length - 1` even when src/dest overlap.  (ie. it will typically only corrupt the memory you asked it to write to.)

Comment: @JoeZ I was refering to using memmove that allows overlap and not memcpy!?

Comment: @rullof :  Oh, ok.  For `memmove()`, it copies from source to destination _as if_ it moved through a third buffer that didn't overlap with either.  (In practice, there's no third buffer.  The _as-if_ wording is there in the specification for esoteric reasons.)  When source and destination overlap, the portion of the source that overlaps the destination will get overwritten by the end of the `memmove()`, for the simple reason that you need to write the entire result at the destination.

Comment: @JoeZ So what is the solution?

Comment: @rullof:  What do you mean by "solution"?  I'm not sure what you perceive the problem to be.  `memmove` will correctly move bytes from source to destination, even when they overlap.  That necessarily overwrites part of the source in the range where they overlap.  The destination will have the correct data.